# Doesn't reach subscribe operator

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

The following snippet of code is using for sending request to server and saving data to database.

```
sessionRepository.getUserId()// from database
    .flatMap(userId -> {
        return profileRepository.editProfile(userId, profile);// send request to server
    })
    .flatMapCompletable(profile1 -> {
        return profileRepository.deleteProfile() // from database                                        
              .andThen(profileRepository.saveProfile(profile1));// to database
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(() -> {
        getViewState().hideLoadingState();
        getViewState().replaceToProperties();
    }, throwable -> {
       throwable.printStackTrace();
    });
```

The problem is that it can not reach subscribe(), but deletes from database and saves to it successfully. Sequence is also kept.

But it works if I do it this way:

`int userId = sessionRepository.getUserId().blockingFirst();// get user id from database`

```
compositeDisposable.add(
    profileRepository.editProfile(userId, profile)// send request to server
        .flatMapCompletable(profile1 -> {
            return profileRepository.deleteProfile()// from database
                   .andThen(profileRepository.saveProfile(profile1));// to database
                    })
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(() -> {
           getViewState().replaceToProperties();                          
           getViewState().hideLoadingState();
           }, throwable -> {                   
          throwable.printStackTrace();
        })
 );
```

Comment: Really strange, but I noticed something awkward in code, your first subscribe consumer is acting like it has no parameters from Functional Interface, try changing `.subscribe(() -> ...)` to `.subscribe(__ -> ...)`. It might be `Completable` however which doesn't use `Consumer` but `Action` in subscribe.

Comment: @Tuby yes, `profileRepository.saveProfile(profile1)` is `Completable.fromAction(() -> ...);`

Comment: Could you add a couple of `doOnComplete`s to see where the signal disappears?

Comment: @akarnokd I've added, and `sessionRepository.getUserId(), profileRepository.editProfile(...)` was not completed. I also `checked doOnLifecycle()` for both of them and method `accept()` of `class LongConsumer`  in `sessionRepository.getUserId().doOnLifecycle()` was called twice: at start of execution and after `doOnComplete()` of `profileRepository.saveProfile(...)`. As I understand it is the reason why subscribe() is not reached.

Comment: Is `sessionRepository.getUserId` like a Room or SQLite source? Those tend to be infinite. Apply `firstOrError` after `getUserId` to make sure only the first response is awaited.

Comment: @akarnokd Room. Yes it helped, thank you a lot. But I can't find error of  infinite requests to database.

Comment: Is there a chance the database is empty?

Comment: No, because I get a property value from there.

Comment: please post the ```getUserId()``` definition and your database library...

Comment: @Appyx I use Room database. 

     `public Flowable<Integer> getUserId() {
            return sessionDao.getSession()
                    .map(session -> {
                        return session.getUserId();
                    });               
        }`

Comment: ok then add ```do{}``` blocks to print the events out of each observable and post it...

and btw, why is your editProfile a Flowable?

Comment: @Appyx I use Flowable because of Retorfit request, as far as I know it is a good practice to use Flowable for network requests.

    editProfile(): doOnRequest(),
    getUserId(): doOnRequest(),
    getUserId(): doOnNext(),
    getUserId(): doOnCancel(),
    editProfile(): doOnNext(),
    deleteProfile(): doOnComplete(),
    saveProfile(): doOnComplete()

Comment: But if you do a GET/POST request to the server it completes after the connection is closed...so I would use a Single or a Completable to communicate in this case

Comment: @Appyx thank you, I'll consider this.

Comment: If saveProfile completes then it should work...you can try to use the non-lambda variant to be sure.